# How to write filter that inspects an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following arrays:

```
 array1 = ["A","B", "C"];
 array2 = ["D", "E", "F"];
 array3 = ["G", "H", "I"];

 combined = [array1, array2, array3];
 select = ["A","H"];
```

I need a filter for 'combined' based on the 'select' array that returns array1 and array3 as A is in Array1, and H is in array3.

This is what I have tried (in typescript)

```
return routes.filter((route: any) =>  
             roles.some((role: string) =>
                 route.config.roles.some((routeRole: string) =>
                     routeRole === role)));
```

It seems to work, but it only works for the first item in the route.config.roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function finder(combined, select) {
  return combined.filter(function (el) {
    return el.some(function (letter) {
      return select.indexOf(letter) > -1;
    });
  });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q92gmpto/)